# Visual C++ Express on Windows7 64-bit?

Tags: visual-c++

Is it possible to normally run Visual C++ Express edition on windows7 64-bit?
Because when I try to install it, the setup window says "visual c++ 2010 express includes the 32-bit visual c++ compiler toolset". 
   I am a student and intend to use the IDE for learning/practicing C language. I don't plan     to create windows-ready applications anytime soon with the windows SDK.
   So, will it allow me to write and compile normally without the 64-bit compiler toolset(on my 64-bit system)? I mean will it make any difference if I don't plan on making applications using SDK? If yes, please explain how? 
   And finally, should I go on and install it or opt for other C/C++ IDE? I previously used Dev C++ but it isn't as great on Windows 7.
   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll be able to run your programs as every other 32-bit application - via WoW64 (Windows-on-Windows64) technology.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows 7 64bit supports pretty much all 32bit applications just fine (except if they depend on some 32bit-only driver components, but most applications don't do that).

Comment: thanks; does the professional edition contain the 64-bit compilers, because I can download it via the microsoft dreamspark program?

Comment: @Adney: it probably does, I'm note entirely sure. Note that you only need the 64-bit compilers if you need to write 64-bit programs yourself (i.e. programs that need huge amounts of memory, usually).

Comment: Well, if you are participating in DreamSpark program - you're definitely not tied to Express version for educational purposes :)